# Managing browser cache

Tags: javascript, css, html, caching, browser-cache

I'm building a web application. I'm linking to separate css and js files and I want to manage cache.
If the script js or the style css file have been updated then force reload and replace that file, else get the file from cache.
Is that possible? How to do that?

Comment: That's GREAT! Sounds like a good idea. Now why have you posted here? You asked no question. I can tell because I did ask a question in this comment. You can tell by the "?" at the end of it. I don't see one in your post.

Comment: agreed, this is not a question. Please try again after your formulate the question by reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you're right :) Is that possible? How to do that?

Comment: @Amirado read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and EDIT your question so that it is relevant

Answer (score 0):

As a default css and javascript file cashed in client browser. when you update your css or javascript file only need update and increase version in HTML header like this:

```
foo.css?ver=002
foo.js?ver=002
```

Comment: That's not a header, that's a query string parameter, and a non-standard (though common) usage of query strings that merits more explanation for this answer to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This depends a lot on the server, as caching in browsers is based on a set of headers sent by the server, including `Cache-Control`, `Expires`, `Etag`, and the way it handles headers from the client, including `If-Modified-Since`, and `If-None-Match`. This allows the browser to try to request that the server return a file *only if* it doesn't already have the latest version; if, based on headers, the server determines that the browser already has the latest version, it can return a response of `304 not modified`.

You can also use "cache buster" query parameters as sia suggested: add a query parameter to the file name, which will be ignored by most servers, but which you can use to indicate that there is a new version of the same file. While the query parameter won't let you control what version is downloaded, it will be part of the key in the browser cache, so when the parameter changes, the browser will download the file again.

There is an excellent rundown of [how HTTP caching works over on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching).